# onclick event on radio input is not triggering function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, radio-button, tampermonkey

I defined an element triggered on certain website and I attached onclick attribute to input elements created in this element. Now I'm trying to trigger the function by choosing either option but instead I'm getting error saying:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: choosenFollowUp is not defined
at HTMLInputElement.onclick"

Here is my code:

```
const choosenFollowUp = () => {
        console.log('choosenFollowUp triggered');
        let radios = document.getElementsByName('radioOption');

        for(let i=0; i<radios.length; i++){
            if(radios[i].checked){
                console.log(radios[i].value);
            }
        }
    }

    let radio = document.createElement('div');
    radio.style.width = '200px';
    radio.style.height = '65px';
    radio.style.backgroundColor = '#dddfe0';
    radio.style.border = '1px solid black';
    radio.style.borderTop = 'none';
    radio.style.borderBottomLeftRadius = '10px';
    radio.style.borderBottomRightRadius = '10px';
    radio.style.position = 'absolute';
    radio.style.top = '0px';
    radio.style.right = '250px';
    radio.innerHTML = `
       <p style="color: black; text-align: center; background-color: #FFA500; color: white; font-weight: 700;">Follow-Up Options</p>
       <div class="choosenOption" style="margin-left: 35px">
           <input type="radio" name="radioOption" value="30"> 30 min</input>
           <input type="radio" name="radioOption" value="60" checked="checked"> 60 min</input>
       </div>
    `

    const radioTrigger = () => {
        if(window.location.href === 'https://websiteAddress.com'){
            const radioParent = document.querySelector("#main-page-content");
            radioParent.appendChild(radio);
            const radioOption = document.getElementsByName('radioOption');

            for(let i=0; i<radioOption.length; i++){
                radioOption[i].setAttribute('onclick', "choosenFollowUp()");
            }
        }
    }
    radioTrigger();
```

1. I already tried to put onclick directly on input radios but the result is the same.
2. I cannot use JQuery.

Comment: `radioOption[i].onclick=choosenFollowUp;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
radioOption[i].addEventListener("click",choosenFollowUp);
```

or delegate:

```
const radioParent = document.querySelector("#main-page-content");
radioParent.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  // here you can check e.target
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I used radioParent.addEventListener("click", choosenFollowUp) :) I recall that I've tried this previously but with choosenFollowUp defined after the radio container and it didn't work. Stucked because of that. With the code from me question and radioParent defined as above it works perfectly.